# how to get residuals plot in ridge regression in r

Tags: r, plot, regression

```
model=lm.ridge(mpg~.,data=mtcars,lambda=seq(0,1000,.1))
select(model)
model1=lm.ridge(mpg~.,data=mtcars,lambda=14.9)
```

I got a ridge regression model
However, I want to get this kind of plot as shown below:

[image]

But I find I cannot use

```
plot(model1)
```

directly
So, what should I do?

Comment: Are you using the `MASS` package for this? It is helpful to clarify where you get `lm.ridge` from so that SO users can reproduce the problem

Comment: Yes, that's right, I've use `MASS` package, thanks for reminding

Comment: you may have to reproduce the graphs by hand. I am not aware of a prebuilt plotting function.